# How do I get the output of curl into a variable in Perl if I invoke it using backtics?

Tags: perl, curl, backticks, qx

I'm trying to get the response of a curl call into a variable in perl.

```
my $foo = `curl yadd yadda`;

print $foo;
```

does not work. When I run this at the command line the curl call prints all its output correctly in the terminal, but the variable is not filled with that data.

Is there a way to do this without installing and calling the Perl curl lib?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It probably sends its stuff to stderr. Try

```
my $foo = `curl yadd yadda 2>&1`;
```

Comment: That did it! thanks!. I'll give you the checkmark if you can add a sentence or two about what 2>&1 actually does and why moving it from stderr to whatever &1 is dumps it into the variable. 

Thanks very much!

Comment: 2>foo means "redirect stderr to file foo". &1 means stdout, i.e., redirect stderr to stdout. You can also do it the other way: ">&2" which means "redirect stdout to stderr". To redirect both stdout and stderr, you can use ">&", i.e. foocommand &>file_with_boththings.txt

Comment: The '2>&1' notation means that file descriptor 2 (stderr) is sent to the same place that file descriptor 1 (stdout) is sent to.  So both standard output and standard error are written to the same place (standard output).  And Perl's backticks capture the standard output of the executed command, hence...

Comment: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html and http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html has some nice info about it also.

Answer (score 5):

You also might consider looking at [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-5.827/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) or even [LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-5.827/lib/LWP/Simple.pm).

Answer (score 4):

What do you really want to do? Use `curl` at all costs, or grab the contents of a web page?

A more perlish way of doing this (which relies on no external programs that may or may not be installed on the next machine where you need to do this) would be:

```
use LWP::Simple;

my $content = get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015438/")
   or die "no such luck\n";
```

If you want to see why the GET failed, or grab multiple pages from the same site, you'll need to use a bit more machinery. `perldoc lwpcook` will get you started.

Answer (score 3):

In the shell `2>` means redirect fileno 2.  Fileno 2 is always what a program sees as stderr.  Similarly, fileno 0 is stdin and fileno 1 is stdout.  So, when you say `2>&1` you are telling the shell to redirect stderr (fileno 2) into stdout (fileno 1).  Since the backticks operator uses the the shell to run the command you specify, you can use shell redirection, so

```
my $foo = `curl yadda yadda 2>&1`;
```

is telling curl to redirect its output into stdout, and since the backtick operator catches stdout, you get what you were looking for.

Comment: thanks... your explanation is morely betterlier worded than the one I picked as the right answer, so, I'm giving it an uptick :)

Answer (score 1):

Very old post, but the *real* way of using curl in backticks is using the appropriate switch of curl.

This switch is **-o** which defines where to send the output.

More from the curl man page:

> Specifying the output as '-' (a single dash) will force the output to
> be done to stdout.

This also prevents having possible errors in *$foo*, which would happen if you redirect the complete STDERR to STDOUT on errors:

```
my $foo = `curl -o - yadd yadda`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$var = `curl "http://localhost" 2>/dev/null`; 
print length($var)
```

`curl` displays progress information on stderr, redirecting that to /dev/null makes it easier to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

This works on my system:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $output = `curl www.unur.com`;

print $output;

__END__

C:\> z1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

etc.

Comment: I think you may be misinterpreting the printing of the curl for the print statement you have there.  Try print "OUTPUT=$output" instead and see if you get the right result.  I did that too and it prints the curl output and then prints "OUTPT=" cause it never got the result into the var. However, the answer above is correct.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel if I remove the print statement, I see the progress information which curl prints to stderr, but not the output of curl. If I put print "OUTPUT=$output", I get OUTPUT=<!DOCTYPE ... etc, so I am not sure what you are talking about. curl's man page is explicit: By default, it outputs to stdout and backticks in Perl capture that output.

Comment: perhaps it's some sort of platform discrepancy. It definitely does not print to stdout for me, and the answer I checked did fix the issue.

Comment: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html -o/--output <file>
Write output to <file> instead of stdout. Maybe this has to do with the 'yadd yadda' you are not showing.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a pipe as if it were a file.

```
$url = "\"http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" . 
"$symbol&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgvper&e=.csv\"";

open CURL, "curl -s $url |" or die "single_stock_quote: Can't open curl $!\n";
$line = <CURL>;
close CURL;
```

Answer (score -1):

It might be that some of the output you want to capture is in standard err, not standard out.  Try this:

```
my $foo = system "curl http://www.stackoverflow.com";
print $foo;
```

Comment: this doesn't do what you think it does.